# $(-\infty, x]$ and $[x,+\infty)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ compact?

Tags: general-topology

How can I prove this? Why can't we use the proof for [x,y] and Supremum here? I suppose because it is not bounded, and we don't know that we have a Supremum/Infimum at all (which we don't). On the other side I don't see how to use the counterexample for $(x,y)$ or $(x,y]$ here.

Definitions:

1. A topological space $X$ is called compact if each open coverage of $X$ has a finite partial coverage, i.e. $I$ is a set and $U_i \subseteq X$ is open
   $(i \in I)$ with $\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i = X$, then a finite subset $J \subseteq I$ exists with $\bigcup_{j\in J} U_j = X$.
2. A subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is called compact, if $A$ is compact in the track topology, i.e. if for a set $I$ and open sets $U_i (i ∈ I)$ with $\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i \supseteq A$ there is always a finite subset $J \subseteq I$, so that $\bigcup_{j\in J} U_j \supseteq A$ applies

Edit: I would like to prove this using this definitions. Means w/o H-B.

Comment: Can you find a finite subcover of the cover by the open sets of the form $(-a,a)$?

Comment: This is not true. See the Heine-Borel Theorem.

Comment: Which definition of compactness do you use? For example, $(x,x+1,x+2,\ldots)$ is clearly a sequence without convergent subsequence.

Comment: Maybe this is the reason for my confusion. I have added the definition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the open cover defined by
$$U_n = (x-1,x+n) = B\left(x-1+\frac{n-1}{2}, \frac{n-1}{2}\right).$$
Notice that this is indeed an open cover for $[x,\infty)$. To see this, let $y\in [x,\infty)$, which is equivalent to $y\geq x$.

This means there exists $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y<x+m$ by the Archimedean Principle. This implies that $y\in U_m$ and we have:
$$[x,\infty) \subseteq \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} U_n $$
So, the collection of $U_n$ is an open cover. We wish to show that there is no finite subcover. Suppose that $U_{m_1},\ldots,U_{m_k}$ is a finite subcover and notice that
$$U_{m_i}\subseteq U_M,$$
where $M = \max\{m_1,\ldots,m_k\}$.
So we have that $[x,\infty)\subseteq U_M$. So in particular for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq x$, we have that
$$n\leq x+M $$
which implies that $x+M$ is an upper bound for $\mathbb{N}$, which contradicts the fact that the natural numbers do not have an upper bound (this can be shown via the [supremum property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property)).

We can construct a similar counterexample for $(-\infty,x].$

Answer (score 1):

Every compact subset of a metric space is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space then any compact subset of $X$ is bounded.

Is either of the intervals you mentioned bounded wrt to the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$? Why or why not?